# How to improve performance of select queries from table with lots of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with almost 100 columns. The type for most of the columns is `Nvarchar(50)`.

When I select rows by query, it takes a long time, depending on the number of rows. Now, the table includes 250,000 rows. It takes a a full minute to get all the rows when I execute:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

I tried to add indexes, but it didn't shorten the time.

How can I build this table in a better way, so that the query's execute time will be shorter?

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Do you have a clustered index on the table? Why are you regularly returning the whole table, it would be better to tailor indexes depending upon how you use the data.

Comment: I have a clustered index on the table- the Pk.

Comment: How many times are you going to query the data for all 100 columns and all 250k rows? Your issue is likely to be just the amount of data you're trying to return.

Comment: I create an application in Wpf that show all the rows in a dataGrid. so that I  have regularly to return the whole table

Comment: every time I run the application,

Comment: Are you creating a summary of the data (I'm assuming you don't actually display all 250k rows)? You could look into indexed views.

Comment: `Select * from Table1` - this returns whole table contents. What kind of optimization are you looking for?

Comment: Indexes are not going to help if you want to get all the data. How much of that minute is *getting* the data, and now much is *displaying* the data? A human can't possibly look at all 250k rows at once, so you probably want to look at some sort of pagination, either get and display a small number of rows, or get them all and cache them, and display a sensible amount

Comment: I select all rows from c# by sqlDataAdapter and I show to user what he selects to show and I also build graphs from all data.

Comment: What if you ask first what the user wants to see and just fetch the needed data? For graphs, you might want to do some kind of summary table.

Comment: The only answer is *don't* load all columns or rows. Load only those that you need. You can't display 100 graphs or 100 grid columns, so why are you trying to load them? This isn't a database problem

Comment: Grids support data virtualization, ie loading only the rows they can display, then requesting additional rows from the database as needed. This is also supported by high performance graphs. Grids also support paging, to load only the rows that a human can handle

Comment: all the above suggested solutions , or create a batch job to run over night , and sync them over a NoSQL database , and then fetch the documents from there , and even the calculated summary table

Comment: @AntJavaDev why??? SQL isn't broken and a NoSQL database *won't* make junk data travel faster over the wire! The OP is asking about simply *loading* data, not transforming it

Comment: @AntJavaDev https://twitter.com/i/moments/801085643547930624

Comment: well you got a point , but i am not quite sure about the faster / slower as well as the database overhead

Comment: You will need to take a look at your execution plan. Often you see your problem there.

Comment: @Sefe even the perfect execution plan won't make a query go faster if it requests 98 columns then discards them

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the size of the table by adjusting the data types to the minimum requirements. Don't use a bigint where an int will suffice, or Unicode types if you are not holding Unicode text and keep data lengths to the minimum requirement. If there are nvarchar(50) columns with a great deal of Nulls, set Sparse to True in the column properties to reduce the amount of data that has to be loaded.

Comment: The actual solution is to simply not load columns that aren't going to be used. You can't fix an application bug by breaking the database

Comment: Tehila has clearly asked how to build the table in a better way so that a Select * statement returns quicker, with no mention of application bugs. The OP may very well be still in the design stage of this part of the application. Also, I think it is assuming too much that the OP would only require a smaller number of columns; there is mention of the data being used for graphs, which likely need all the data at hand.

Comment: There's no database optimization that can fix sending 98 unneeded columns. You can't fix a bad application design at the database level, because the database isn't at fault

Comment: I can only draw attention to my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index with includes. If you make sure that the include contains only the columns you select, SQL server can run the query exclusively on the index, which improves performance.

For example a table...

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
    Column1 INT,
    Column2 INT,
    --....
    Column100 INT
)
```

...with a query on a subset of the columns:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
WHERE Column1 > 1000
```

You can create the index

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Example
    ON Example(Column1)
    INCLUDE (Column2, Column3)
```

Since SQL Server can get all the information it needs from the index, it won't touch the table. However, you will need more space for index than without includes, because the data from the table is now stored redundandly in the index.

Comment: This won't help at all if the OP is going to load 100 *columns* but only use 10

Answer (score 0):

Your Execution plan will give you answer, check it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'SELECT * FROM Table1' then Indexes won't make any difference. SQL will need to read the entire table from Disk to Buffer. If you can't get away from Selecting all columns then look at what record-sets are most often returned, i.e. Transactions from 2016. If this is the case, then you can introduce Partitioning (Enterprise), or if you are on SQL Standard create a 'Filtered Covering Index' (including all columns) that only contains records from 2016. If you can afford the extra update overhead then SQL will use the smaller index to fulfill the bulk of user demand.